# Start Activity of 2nd app from 1st app in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, runtime-error

I am new to android development. I am trying to start an activity of 2nd app from 1st app on button click. But my app gets stopped. i might be doing something wrong with the intent.
This is the LOGCAT:

```
02-12 18:06:50.948: D/gralloc_goldfish(1247): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-12 18:07:02.338: D/AndroidRuntime(1247): Shutting down VM
02-12 18:07:02.338: W/dalvikvm(1247): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad1b90)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Process: smd.homework1.question2, PID: 1247
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     ... 11 more
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=textViewActivity }
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at smd.homework1.question2.MainActivity.function1(MainActivity.java:36)
02-12 18:07:02.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     ... 14 more
```

line 36 is `startActivity(i);`
button click function is:

```
public void function1(View v){
    Intent i= new Intent("textViewActivity");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In the mainifest of

```
<activity
    android:name="Activity2"
    android:label="@string/a2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="textViewActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: make sure you have the function you are calling using `android:onClick`

Comment: have you declare your another activity in mainefest file?

Comment: @hypd09 yes. I have posted the function. And from the logcat i can see that the error is in the function on `startActivity(i);`

Comment: @rajshree yes i have declared both the activities in their respective apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android every application is a separate process, you can't do any communication except via intents, so you need to send an action intent from app1 and implement a broadcast-receiver in app2 that catches the intent and fire your activity.

```
app1->activityA->send intent->app2 receiver->start activity-> activityB
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) is another way offered by official doc where you can skip broacastreceivers as your activity will be the receiver of a certain [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: I am using intent as can be seen by my code. But we have not studied receivers yet. And our instructor told us that we can do the task with implicit intents.

Comment: Thanks! These links are really usefull!

Answer (score 2):

Declare the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` as

```
<activity
     android:name="Activity2"
     android:label="@string/a2"
     android:exported="true" >
</activity>
```

The code to execute it is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.Activity2"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Replace `com.example` with the second app package name and `com.example.Activity2` with the package-qualified activity name.

---

Declare the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` as

```
<activity
     android:name="Activity2"
     android:label="@string/a2" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.example.myintent" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The code to execute it is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.myintent");
startActivity(intent);
```

Replace `com.example.myintent` with your intent name.

Comment: using the 2nd app package name will make it explicit intent but i want to use implicit intent(because it is required in the assignment).

Comment: assignment... help... ARE YOU CHEATING? :)

Comment: No. I am taking help from those who know. I could have asked my instructor but he will be available on Saturday. So I thought i could use some help from you guys.

Comment: Just joking - not trying to scare anyone! :)